# Laravel - Text input search not working on button click

Tags: laravel

I am creating a search criteria whereby the text input on button click will displat the result on table td. No thing change and there is no error message displayed

I have written the controller and view

Controller

```
    public function playersPerGame()
    {       

        $data['title'] = 'Games Report';
        $games= GamePoint::select('game_point.game_name','game_point.description','game_point.point_assigned','game_point.created_at'); 
        $render=[];
        if(isset($request->game_name))
        {
            $games=$games->where('game_name','like','%'.$request->game_name.'%');
            $render['name']=$request->name;
        }

        $games= $games->paginate(15);
        $games= $games->appends($render);
        $data['games'] = $games;
        return view('report.playersPerGame',$data); //             
    }
```

View

```
        {{ Form::model(request(),['method'=>'get']) }}
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            {{ Form::text('game_name',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Game name']) }}

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            {{ Form::submit('Search',['class'=>'btn btn-warning']) }}
            <a href="" class="btn btn-info">Export</a>
        </div>
        {{ Form::close() }}
    </div>

          <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
        @if(Session::has('flash_message'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ Session::get('flash_message') }}
        </div>
        @endif 
        @if(count($games))
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped table-condesed" id="game_info_table">
    <caption></caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>#</td>
            <td>Games</td>
            <td>Description</td>            
            <td>Point Assigned</td>
            <td>Date Uploaded</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($games as $key => $gaming)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
                <td>{{ $gaming->game_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $gaming->description }}</td>
                <td>{{ $gaming->point_assigned }}</td>
                <td>{{ $gaming->created_at }}</td>

            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

On button click, I expect it to display result based on the text input but nothing happen

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved it myself. I forgot to add (Request $request). Thanks

Comment: delete your post